# How can I use variable defined in build.gradle in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, variables, gradle, resources

I have a variable in `build.gradle` (Module: app) which counts the build number (number of compilations to be precise:

```java
String content = ""

def buildCountFile = new File("c:\\projects\\aviacheck\\spec\\aviacheck-build-counter.txt")

if (buildCountFile.exists()) {
    content = buildCountFile.getText('UTF-8')
}
int count = 0;
if (content.isNumber()) {
    count = content.toInteger() + 1;
}
buildCountFile.write(count.toString())
// build counter ends

buildTypes {
    debug{
        resValue "string", "bNr", count.toString()
    }
    release {
        resValue "string", "bNr", count.toString()
    }
}
```

which is stored in "bNr".

Of course I can use it in code by `getResoures()`, but I would like to concatenate it in `strings.xml` with one more string without writing code.

So, defining version compilation like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY appVer "1.2">
    ]>

<resources>
//    ........
    <string name="ver">"&appVer; Build: &bNr;</string>
//    ........
</resources>
```

Unfortunately,  `&bNr` remains unresolved.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to concatenate it in strings.xml with one more string without writing code

That is not supported, sorry.

> unfortunately &bNr keeps unresolved.

There is no HTML entity by that name.